# More than one FQDN or DNS for Azure Public IP

Tags: azure, dns, ip, fqdn

is it possible to have more than one DNS from AZURE running on a public Azure IP at a time ?

I understand the comamnd is

```
az network public ip update
```

in my case

```
az network public-ip update --ids *** --dns-name b***y-test5
az network public-ip update --ids *** --dns-name b***y-test5-io
```

But if i run one, the other one will be inaccessible in a short time.
I need this for Kubernetes routing with ingress on different services.

Is ther any way to register both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `az network public-ip update` only updates with one DNS name. If you want two DNS names for one service, you could use another alias via adding a CNAME record.

If so, you need a public domain such as`contoso.com`, you could [add a CNAME record to your domain's DNS record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/47283). For example, add a CNAME named `www` that maps to the Azure created DNS name like `vm.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com` for your service in the DNS zone in your domain provider. If so, you will access the public IP address via two DNS names `vm.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com` and `www.contoso.com`.

Additionally, you could optionally [host your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns) and configure its records in Azure.

Comment: Let me try this ... however this is initiated from my DNS provider and i think i can not automate this mapping approach correct ?

Comment: Yes, but if you can host your domain in Azure DNS, then you can manage it with Azure CLI, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Ok so the solution worked for me i got this all running now.. my provider is just a little slow on changing cname... i really will consider using azure